# my web scraping does not work and i don t know what the problem is

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get("https://www.arukereso.hu/mobiltelefon-c3277/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "head")

print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: You have not said what problem you are having. Please include a copy of the error. You may also wish to look at the Markdown guide for code blocks: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: my code doesn t have an error, just don t shows anything, it shows no text, jus prcess  finished with exit code 0

Comment: What editor are you using? Please provide a screenshot of your code running

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the entire html content (not sure what you want to achieve with the "head"):

Try replacing

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "head")
```

with

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
```